# Safari Extension Taking Screenshot

Tags: safari, screenshot, safari-extension

I am developing safari browser extension which should have taking screenshot functionality.

Chrome and Firefox has their own apis to take SS of the current window document.
I could not find any safari specific/API documentation for it.
[The Windows and Tabs API](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH17-SW1)

What would be the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SafariBrowserTab` has a [`visibleContentsAsDataURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/SBrowserTabClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/SafariBrowserTab/visibleContentsAsDataURL) method to get the image data of the currently visible content.

For example, in your global page:

```
safari.application.addEventListener('command', performCommand, false);

// Perform e.g. when toolbar button is clicked
function performCommand(event) {
    if (event.command === 'captureTab') {
        var tab = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab;
        tab.visibleContentsAsDataURL(function(imgdata) {
            //console.log(imgdata);
            // Do something...
            // e.g. Send to an injected script to display image on page:
            tab.page.dispatchMessage('imgData', imgdata);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great. For people who are looking for handy reference can refer at https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/SafariExtensionsReference/SafariExtensionsReference.pdf