# how would you take a screenshot in a iOS Safari Extension?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, screenshot, webpage-screenshot, ios8-share-extension

Building a Safari (desktop) extension, one have access to screenshot from tab.visibleContentsAsDataURL(); it works brilliantly, lightning fast. Something like this: [Safari Extension Taking Screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318263/safari-extension-taking-screenshot)

On iOS, we tried:

- Html2Canvas (it didn't produce good enough results); http://html2canvas.hertzen.com
- a hidden UIWebview in the extension (cause troubles with memory in the extension)

What would be the equivalent on iOS inside a share extension?
In other words: how would you take a screenshot in a iOS Safari Extension?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to obtain a solution?

Comment: still not; we have a temporary image created by the extension for now. This makes me sad :(

Comment: can you kindly post your solution to [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33119727/take-screenshot-of-host-app-using-ios-share-action-extensions)